CheckApSignatures VLAD test is failing with Outdated Manifest error (apsigntool)
I am seeing the following error when attempting to check in my Code Flow PR on PFGold repository.
SIGNEDFOLDER: ERROR: Failed Signing Verification: Error checking folder c:\PFGold\data\Autopilot\OverlakeSocOsUpdate\SocOsUpdateDD: Outdated manifest. Please re-sign the AP Signature.csv located at c:\PFGold\data\Autopilot\OverlakeSocOsUpdate\SocOsUpdateDD. Tips: sync enlistment, check if any files need to be resolved and ensure your enlistment does not exclude files under this folder (run 'sd client' to see any excluded paths)

I do not understand why it says my 'manifest outdated' because the signing was done with the below command just shortly before I tried to submit my change:
c:\PFGold\data\Autopilot\OverlakeSocOsUpdate\SocOsUpdateDD>apsigntool --split-sign -m -w data -i VE-ROOT/COSINE/SOC-Impactful -d ame

Description of the PR: deleting a folder that only contains an ApSignature file from its parent folder.
Files included in the change:


c:\PFGold\data\Autopilot\OverlakeSocOsUpdate\SocOsUpdateDD\dns.raw.v\ApSignature.csv (delete)



c:\PFGold\data\Autopilot\OverlakeSocOsUpdate\SocOsUpdateDD\ApSignature.csv (edit)



I tried to submit the PR after obtaining approval from my team member and after having the manifests signed via the split signing method on the Azure-Gold-Config repository on my SAW machine. But that's when I saw the above error.
